# GATE SUMMA configuration

Tags: java, plugins, gate

I am trying to use the GATE SUMMA from the java. I am trying to run the files included in the tutorial. I have downloaded both ANNIE and SUMMA plugins seperately. What I dont understand is this part in the configuration.

```
 Gate.init();
            // you have to register the plugins from GATE you want to use
             Gate.getCreoleRegister().addDirectory(new URL("file:///"+anniePluginDir));
            // you have to register the SUMMA plugin to have access to its resources
            Gate.getCreoleRegister().addDirectory(new URL("file:///"+summaPluginDir));
            // now create your controller
```

What does this mean `you have to register the plugins from GATE you want to use`
Even providing an plugin path throws and error

```
The method addDirectory(URL) is undefined for the type CreoleRegister
```

I see that Creole is a type of configuration management under GATE framework. Do I need to have an xml file created for that?

The full class file is as shown on the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/da7db179a72717ae1db0bef94224f16c) ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to have an xml file created for that?

Yes,

```
Gate.getCreoleRegister().addDirectory(URL)
```

Registers a GATE plugin directory, which has to contain the `creole.xml` file.

ANNIE plugin directory is a part of common GATE installation (see  `$GATE_HOME\plugins\ANNIE` dir).

I don't know about SUMMA, but I guess it also have such a directory somewhere...

---

But

> The method addDirectory(URL) is undefined for the type CreoleRegister

means that your code was created for a different version of GATE. Apparently, your current version of GATE doesn't have the `addDirectory(URL)` method. I think it was replaced by 
`CreoleRegister.registerDirectories(URL)` method in the current GATE (ver. 8.x series).

Comment: Yes, you right its now `` I think it was replaced by CreoleRegister.registerDirectories(URL) method in the current GATE (ver. 8.x series)``.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what @dedek said. The actual code is

```
 URL ANNIEcreoleURL = new URL("resources/plugins/ANNIE");
 Gate.getCreoleRegister().registerDirectories(ANNIEcreoleURL);
```