# Java library : Gate Creole ResourceInstantiationException

Tags: java, gate, creole

I am using [GATE](https://gate.ac.uk/) library and am getting the error

```
gate.creole.ResourceInstantiationException: Couldn't get resource data for com.jpetrak.gate.stringannotation.extendedgazetteer2.ExtendedGazetteer2.

You may need first to load the plugin that contains your resource.
For example, to create a gate.creole.tokeniser.DefaultTokeniser
you need first to load the ANNIE plugin.

Go to the menu File->Manage CREOLE plugins or use the method
Gate.getCreoleRegister().registerDirectories(pluginDirectoryURL).
```

I am initialised my plugins folder and also have added the following line

```
Gate.getCreoleRegister().registerDirectories(new URL("file:///home/latest/plugins/ANNIE"));
```

and folder ANNIE contains the file cerole.xml

as told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42293091/gate-summa-configuration)

why am I still getting the error?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to register any plugin you are using.

The class

> com.jpetrak.gate.stringannotation.extendedgazetteer2.ExtendedGazetteer2

is a GATE processing resource from a very old version of [gateplugin-stringannotation](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gateplugin-stringannotation/) .

So except ANNIE, you have to register the directory of this plugin as well.